# Cannot convert basic disk to dynamic disk. Not enough space

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, dynamic-disk

I'm trying to convert a disk from basic to dynamic to mirror two volumes on another disk of equal size. I have used the disk before, but it is currently wiped clean, not even partitioned.

In disk management I see "465.32 GB - Unallocated" and "450 MB - Healthy (Recovery Partition)" on the disk.

When I try to convert it into a dynamic disk I get an error saying there isn't enough space on the disk.

Where do I even start to troubleshoot this? I'm on Windows 10 and I have used this particular disk for this very purpose before.

Comment: I did solve this problem. I used the disk with "Storage Spaces". That also wiped the disk clean INCLUDING the Recovery Partition. I then deleted the storage space it was included in and went back to Disk Management. Behold! The last recovery partition was gone I could convert the disk to a dynamic one.

Answer (score 1):

You get this problem when you have a large unallocated space. Create a dummy volume in this space, and then you will be able to convert the disk to dynamic. You can then delete the dummy volume if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help when you already have 4 partitions (such as the 4 that Windows installs by default), are trying to add a fifth partition and get prompted to first convert the disk to "Dynamic". When trying to do so you get the error about not enough space. Unfortunately you can't create a dummy volume in this case. But perhaps I could extend the main system volume to cover that space. Not sure if that fixes it, but I might give it a try, as long as I can shrink it later.